# Kibana and Elasticsearch compatibility

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I want to use Kibana with my Elasticsearch instance. Having downloaded the latest Kibana instance, I realized that it isn't compatible with my Elasticsearch version:

> Kibana: This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch 1.4.4 or higher on all nodes. I found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: 
>   Elasticsearch v1.3.1

Where can I find what versions of Kibana are compatible with which releases of Elasticsearch?

Comment: Kibana 3 works with pretty much any version between 0.7 -1.4.4. I believe it would be safe to use Kibana 3 if you are using various versions of Kibana in your clusters. You can find a version here . https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/kibana-3-1-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have Elasticsearch version of 1.4.4 or higher to integrate kibana.

Comment: and after 7 years `[2022-08-01T21:38:15.006+00:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] This version of Kibana (v8.3.3) is incompatible with the following Elasticsearch nodes in your cluster: v7.17.3 @ 10.233.77.24:9200 (10.233.77.24), v7.17.3 @ 10.233.81.216:9200 (10.233.81.216), v7.17.3 @ 10.233.66.217:9200 (10.233.66.217)
`

Answer (score 9):

Here's an Elastic Search / Kibana compatibility matrix as taken from https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#show_compatibility

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Kibana 4 will work with elasticsearch 1.5. You can download Elasticsearch 1.5 and then connect to kibana. It will connect.